# How to set min date for Kendo datetime picker

Tags: kendo-ui, datetimepicker

I've a Kendo template and that template contains a textbox like below with datetime picker.

```
<script id="popup_editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <input data-role="datepicker" data-bind="value: datePickerValue" />
</script>
```

Now I want to set min value for this. i.e I don't want to permit to select previous days than today. Is an example available on the web?

Comment: You mean to say you wanted to Initialize the date picker with already assign min value beyond past user cant select anything?

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
var myDatePicker = $("#myDatePicker").kendoDatePicker().data("kendoDatePicker");
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDate();
var month = today.getMonth() + 1;
var year = today.getFullYear();
myDatePicker.min(new Date(year,month,day));
```

Comment: it will work independently.. but I'm using datepicker in my template like above code

Comment: Kendo provides many date helpers. You can simply call `kendo.date.today()` to get the current date as a JavaScript `Date` object. Note: I believe this helper was added in Q2 2013.

Answer (score 3):

*Usually*, you can do some javascript here:

```
var myDatePicker = $("#date").kendoDatePicker().data("kendoDatePicker");
myDatePicker.min(new Date());
```

but I'm not sure if it's going to work within your template that way. Maybe it's a start.

Comment: What worked for me was removing the kendoDatePicker() call, e.g.:

var myDatePicker = $("#date").data("kendoDatePicker");
myDatePicker.min(new Date());

Answer (score 2):

Ok I had to implement something similar recently and found a straightforward way to do this. I realize this is way too late, but I found this question, while I was doing my research.

Say the below is your template: (Simplified for brevity)

```
    <div class="k-block k-shadow">
        <p>Contract Start Date: </p>
        <input type="text"  tabindex="7"
            class="k-input k-textbox"
            name="Contract_Start_Date"
            id="Contract_Start_Date"
            data-bind="value:Contract_Start_Date"
            data-format="MMMM yyyy"
            data-start="year"
            data-depth="year"
            data-change="setContractMinEnd"
            data-role="datepicker" />
    </div>
    <div class="k-block k-shadow">
        <p>Contract End Date: </p>
        <input type="text"  tabindex="8"
            class="k-input k-textbox"
            name="Contract_End_Date"
            id="Contract_End_Date"
            data-bind="value:Contract_End_Date"
            data-format="MMMM yyyy"
            data-start="year"
            data-depth="year"
            data-role="datepicker" />
    </div>
```

The below code for the Contract_Start_Date field assigns a JS function to the "Change" event of that field:

```
data-change: setContractMinEnd
```

I added the above function in a script block to go out with the page. And now every time the start date is changed the end date gets a min value which is the start date:

```
function setContractMinEnd() {
    var edval = $('#Contract_Start_Date').data("kendoDatePicker");
    var sdval = $('#Contract_End_Date').data("kendoDatePicker");
    if (sdval && edval) {                        
        edval.min(sdval.value());
    }
}
```

You can obviously get fancy with that logic and set the below or something to that effect:

```
 edval.min(new Date())
```

Hope it helps someone...

Comment: If i have to set min date intially before selecting the date. So that user can't select the previous date. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass data-min="your Date in proper format" in html input.

```
<script id="popup_editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <input data-role="datepicker" data-bind="value: datePickerValue" data-min="min_date_value" />
</script>
```

This will not even show dates beyond the minimum value.