# How to compare two Dates both Month and Year in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following date picker fields in my view. I want to validate that fromDate must be less than todate.

```
     @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.FromDate)
           .Format("{0:MM/yyyy}")
           .Depth(CalendarView.Year)
           .Start(CalendarView.Year)
          )
```

And From Date

```
      @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.ToDate)
           .Format("{0:MM/yyyy}")
           .Depth(CalendarView.Year)
           .Start(CalendarView.Year)
          )
```

I used this Jquery but it only check the month Part. How can compare both the month and the year

```
 function validateDateRange() {
        var messageText = '';
        var fromDate = $('#FromDate').val();
        var toDate = $('#ToDate').val();

        if ((fromDate > toDate) && (toDate != null || toDate.length != 0) && (fromDate != null || fromDate.length != 0)) {
            messageText = 'start Date Must be greater than or equal to the end date.';
        }        
       
        return messageText;
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be easier to restrict available date interval in your datepicker, using some `maxDate` / `minDate` attributes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set min date for kendo datetime picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850979/how-to-set-min-date-for-kendo-datetime-picker)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov that didnt work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just change the date values into timestamp

```
function validateDateRange() {
    var messageText = '';
    var fromText = $('#FromDate').val();
    var toText = $('#ToDate').val();
    // since from/to texts has different date format we need to change it
    // to a format new Date() would accept
    var fromSplit = fromText.split("/");
    var toSplit = toText.split("/");
    // just put 1 day if it's not necessary
    fromText = fromSplit[1] + "-" + fromSplit[0] + "-" + "1";
    toText = toSplit[1] + "-" + toSplit[0] + "-" + "1";
    // multiplying date by 1 will return a timestamp
    var fromDate = new Date(fromText) * 1; 
    var toDate = new Date(toText) * 1;

    /* Shouldn't be start date be lesser than end date? but whatever */
    if (fromDate < toDate) {
        messageText = 'start Date Must be greater than or equal to the end date.';
    }        
   
    return messageText;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  i tried that now its not validating at all it used to compare the month part. but  i like the approach

Comment: @Rob maybe because it didn't convert right, can you tell me what are the values from fromDate, toDate? What I tried that worked was just a simple `<input type="date">`. Which is yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: I have the two date fields i used is in my quotation, i used kendo date pickers

Comment: yeah I'm guessing the conversion didn't went well because of the date format you have `MM/yyyy` which `new Date()` wont accept.

Comment: Ah, but i liked your solution those dates has to be in MM/yyyy format

Comment: @Rob what I could suggest is to convert the date string youself before using `new Date()`.. too long to put here I'll just update the answer

Comment: Is there any other way to try this?

Comment: there that should do it

Comment: Oh i didnt see that, let me try it

Comment: If you could tell me what's inside `$('#FromDate').val(); $('#ToDate').val();`

Comment: masterpreenz  tried  console.log(fromText); and consol.log(totext) and selected fromdate = 05/2020 and todate 01/2018 fin the two datepickers and in  console log i get `2020-05-1 & 01/2018` format looks different

Comment: maaan `totext = toSplit[1] + "-" + toSplit[0] + "-" + "1";` toText has wrong spelling. If you actually copied the entire code

Answer (score 0):

try Moment.js it has a lot for features, you can simply calculate like this.

```
var a = moment([2008, 9]);
var b = moment([2007, 0]);

a.diff(b, 'years');       // 1
a.diff(b, 'years', true); // 1.75


var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days') // 1
```